# What's the ipad font for these texts?

Tags: iphone, ipad, font-family

[image]

Can someone tell me what's **the font family names** for above texts (title, subtitle, author & content)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

block 1,2,4 are serif, maybe times new roman.

block 3 is san-serif, maybe helvetica, or arial.

Answer (score 0):

Most newspapers have their own proprietary fonts.

Sometimes the production information will tell you.

You could use the Font Book app that comes with your Mac to help get an approximate match